# How to convert cumulative data to daily one?

Tags: python, numpy, inverse, cumulative-sum

I have a list of cumulative transferred data by link and periods when data transfer is started and ended. In other words, elements of `times` is periods of days; elements of `data` are sum of **all** data transferred by this link to the end of current transfer:

```
data = [0.85, 1.6, 1.85, 2.89, 3.56, 4.05, 5.56, 7.89]
times = [[0.5, 1.3], [1.8, 2.1], [2.9, 2.99], [3.5, 3.59], [3.6, 4.1], [4.2, 4.35], [4.65, 4.76], [4.85, 5.5]]
```

Is there any python or numpy way how can I convert cumulative data to daily (`[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4,], [4, 5], [5, 6]`) statistics of transferred data?

**P.S** Daily data means how much data were transferred particularly between `0` and `1` period (`1` and `2` and so on).

For example, I want to find transferred data between `0` day and `1` day. In the period `[0.5, 1.3]` `0.85 GB` of data were transferred. So I have to find a share of `0.85 GB` which particulary transferred between `[0, 1]`.
`0.85 GB * (1-0.5) days / (1.3-0.5) days = 0.53 GB` And so on.

Comment: What does "daily" mean here?

Comment: So, what's the expected output for the sample case?

Comment: @Divakar updated again

Comment: Okay, now this is confusing a bit. How did `0.85` from `data` correspond to `[0.5, 1.3]`? Is it because `0.85` is the first element in `data`? So, by that theory, we should have the number of elems in `data` and `times` the same, which isn't the case as `data` has 8 elems, whereas `times` has 7.

Comment: @Divakar yes. Edited. It means that some man started to send 0.85 GB at `0.5` moment and finished to do it at `1.3` moment.

Comment: That was a bit deviant from what I thought initially! Updated my solution accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.split` to chunk the data into daily arrays. First you need the indices that define the edges of each day; for this you can use `np.histogram` where you define the bins that represent the edges of your days. Then cumsum to get indices of the edges of each day.

```
hist, bins = np.histogram(times, bins=range(5)) # 5 is number of days
chunked = np.split(data, hist.cumsum())
```

Chunked should now be a list of arrays where each array contains the value for each day. You can apply whatever reducing function you want to this.

```
print(chunked)   
# [array([0.85]), array([1.6, 1.85]), ...]

map(np.sum, chunked)
```

Note the times/values arrays must be sorted for split to work.

...

More readable but much slower, you can select data for each day.

```
days = np.floor(times)
chunked = [data[days == day] for day in range(5)]
```

Comment: Is it possible to consider the fact that some transfers started at `0` day and finished at `1` day?

Comment: I don't know how you'd do this in a numpy way. But your question is heading in a direction that's very particular to the task you want to solve (ie not useful to other users of SO). You should get some pen and paper and work out a solution, then you can ask how to optimise any slow code with numpy.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do soomething like this -

```
lims = np.arange(data.size)+1
col0 = lims - times[:,0]
col1 = times[:,1] - lims
lens = times[:,1] - times[:,0]

out = data*col0/lens
shares = data*(col1/lens)
out[1:] += shares.cumsum()[:-1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [144]: data
Out[144]: array([ 0.85,  1.6 ,  1.85,  2.89,  3.56,  4.05,  5.56,  7.89])

In [145]: times
Out[145]: 
array([[ 0.5 ,  1.3 ],
       [ 1.8 ,  2.1 ],
       [ 2.9 ,  2.99],
       [ 3.5 ,  3.59],
       [ 3.6 ,  4.1 ],
       [ 4.2 ,  4.35],
       [ 4.65,  4.76],
       [ 4.85,  5.5 ]])

In [146]: out
Out[146]: 
array([   0.53125   ,    1.38541667,    2.90763889,   16.70208333,
         -2.55102778,   29.67297222,   55.3047904 , -138.46269211])
```

Comment: First element is correct ...  but others like 118, 38, 16, 48 uhhh

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich Explain the expected output for the second element in your sample case?

Comment: how much data is transferred between `1` and `2`. So we have two periods [0.5, 1.3] and [1.8, 2.1]. A share from first interval is `0.85 * (1.3-1) / (1.3-0.5)` and share from second interval is `1.6 * (2-1.8) / (2.1 - 1.8)` .  Equals `1.3854 GB`

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich `1.6 * (2-1.8) / (2.1 - 1.8) == 1.06666`  and not `1,3854`, unless I missed something?

Comment: Sure, but a period [1, 2] also includes a share from [0.5, 1.3]. You miss it  `0.85 * (1.3-1) / (1.3-0.5)`

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich If I could bother you one more time, what would be the third output element? Would be better to add these into the question itself.

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich See if the edited solution works for you. If not, please edit the question with the expected output and explanation for at least the first three outputs.

Answer (score 1):

@Divakar has already posted the correct numpy solution, here's a simple python one:

```
import math
data = [0.85, 1.6, 1.85, 2.89, 3.56, 4.05, 5.56, 7.89]
times = [0.5, 1.3, 1.8, 2.9, 3.5, 3.6, 4.2, 4.65]
daily = [0] * 7

for i, t in enumerate(times):
    daily[int(math.floor(t))] += data[i]

print daily
```